# display two objects by for loop django

Tags: python, html, django

my template has a timeline structure.. so 1 object is left aligned and other is right aligned .. i want to display them alternatively within a for loop.. content from same model but alignments of divs are Diffrent..

```
<ul class="timeline">
                            
                            <li class="timeline-right">
                                <div class="timeline-badge">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                    <p class="date-inverted wow slideInLeft">{{Experience.first.FromDate}} -{{Experience.first.ToDate}}</p>
                                </div><!-- end timeline-badge -->
                                <div class="timeline-panel wow slideInRight">
                                    <div class="experience-content">
                                        <h4>{{Experience.first.Designation}}</h4>
                                        <h5>{{Experience.first.Department}}</h5>
                                        <p>{{Experience.first.ShortNote}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--end timeline-panel -->
                            </li><!-- end timeline-right -->
                            <li class="timeline-left">
                                <div class="timeline-badge">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                    <p class="date wow slideInRight">Oct 2015 - Nov 2016</p>
                                </div><!-- end timeline-badge -->
                                <div class="timeline-panel wow slideInLeft">
                                    <div class="experience-content">
                                        <h4>MGS PVT. LTD.</h4>
                                        <h5>Senior Designer </h5>
                                        <p>The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- end timeline-panel -->
                            </li><!-- end timeline-left -->
```

models. py

```
  class Experience(models.Model):
          Designation = models.CharField(max_length=150)
          Department = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
          Organisation =models.CharField(max_length=150)
          ShortNote   = models.CharField(max_length=200)
          FromDate  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
          ToDate = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

         def __str__(self):
               return self.Designation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) with [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter in the template:

```
{% for exp in object_list %}
    <li class="{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}timeline-right{% else %}timeline-left{% endif %}">
        <div class="timeline-badge">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            <p class="date-inverted wow slideInLeft">{{exp.FromDate}} -{{exp.ToDate}}</p>
        </div><!-- end timeline-badge -->
        <div class="timeline-panel wow slideInRight">
            <div class="experience-content">
                <h4>{{exp.Designation}}</h4>
                <h5>{{exp.Department}}</h5>
                <p>{{exp.ShortNote}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**FYI:** please follow [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide when naming attributes in a class.

Comment: thanks brother..  but still there is a problem..  <p class="date-inverted wow slideInLeft">{{exp.FromDate}} -{{exp.ToDate}}</p>   should be on left side when timeline is on right ... it is now overlapping.. (both are on one side) ..  <p class="date wow slideInRight">Oct 2015 - Nov 2016</p> should be there..

Comment: You can implement something simillar to answer, like: `% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 %}slideInRight{% else %}slideInRight{% endif %}`

Comment: hi please check this screenshot...i am new to django so i can nnot figure out the issue even after kind help from youhttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1wKS79fhxH88j8VN1tEGir3VNTYdgc-9E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hi mate... it is now working perfectly.. though took some time for date alignment .. all because of you.. thnks..

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'cycle' tag inside the for loop.

```
{% for o in some_list %}
<tr class="{% cycle 'timeline-right' 'timeline-left' %}">
    ...
</tr>
```

{% endfor %}